# Do I have to replace the LCD if the iPad screen is cracked?

Tags: screen, ipad, repair

I have an iPad 2 that my grandson dropped and the screen is now cracked around the edge, none of the cracks extend into the touch area of the screen.  All of the cracks are in the outside edge where the screen is black.  Do I have to repair the LCD or is that something that can be fixed without replacing the LCD?

Comment: Difficult to say because we can't see how damaged the iPad is.

Answer (score 1):

If the LCD screen is not damaged (no dead pixels) then you *probably* only need to replace the actual glass front touch panel, or *digitizer*, and do not need to change the LCD.  This can pick up relatively cheaply ([$90](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/iPad/iPad-2-Front-Panel/IF112-000), or eBay). You just prise the front panel off, and leaving the LCD in place, replace it with a new one.

Google for this video "**How to: Fix a broken front panel on your iPad 2 or iPad 3**" on youtube. It give you a good idea of what is involved. Or check out [Repair Ipad 2 Glass](http://www.instructables.com/id/Repair-Ipad-2-Glass/?ALLSTEPS)

To be honest, you are probably better sending it to a third party to get the digitizer replaced.

Good luck.