# My cracked iPad 2

Tags: ipad, backup

I cracked my iPad 2 really bad. I cant see nothing but white shattered circles. I was wondering if I repaired it will all my pictures in the gallery will still be there?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you connect the iPad to a computer and back up the contents before the repair? Also, cracked glass and physical damage rarely causes connector problems or prevents a sync with iTunes from completing. You'd only have to [repair the screen if the digitizer didn't work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168062/do-i-have-to-replace-the-lcd-if-the-ipad-screen-is-cracked) enough to tap one time to accept a pairing request if needed.

There's no guarantee that delaying the backup will help and there's a chance that the damage could cause a failure of the logic parts or storage parts - especially when a repair tech starts working on the screen.

Apple will help you locate backups before they accept the iPad for service, so I would start there and see if your gallery is already on iCloud or in a backup.